# Loop to find decrementing whole word string in a list

Tags: python

I have a string variable that is a person's first and middle names, which have been accidentally concatenated. Let's call it `firstMiddle="johnadam"`

I need to identify what's the first name and what isn't, and then split them into different variables. So I have this big text file full of first names, and the idea is that you check the full `firstMiddle` string to see if it's in the list, and if it isn't, then you decrement by one character and retry. (if you increment you fail, e.g. `"max"` from `"maxinea"`)

I have tried writing this a hundred different ways, and my problem seems to be that I can't get it to x in y a whole word (this \b regex stuff only works on actual strings and not string variables?). The best outcome I had decremented `"johnadam"` down to `"johna"` because there is a name `"johnathan"` in the list. Now I can't even remember how I did that and my current code decrements just once and then quits even though `nameToMatch` in `nameList == False`.

I'm a total noob. I know I'm doing something very obviously stupid. Please help. Here's some code:

```
firstMiddle = "johnadam"
nameToCheck = firstMiddle

for match in nameList:
    if nameToCheck not in nameList:
        nameToCheck = nameToCheck[:-1]
        break

firstName = nameToCheck
middleName = firstMiddle.partition(nameToCheck)[2]
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see a small portion of this input file, and clarification on what you mean by "increment" and "decrement". I don't understand what it means that `"johnadam"` is "decremented" down to `"johna"`. Do you mean you're just looking in the previous element?

Comment: you only want to break out of the loop when you find a match ...

Comment: @aliteralmind It's literally a txt file with a list of names. When I say decrement the string I mean string = string[:-1]. In other words, if you take "maxinea" it would search maxinea and fine nothing, then maxinea[:-1], which is "maxine" and would find it.

Comment: @Gabriel thanks for pointing that out. I removed the break and now I'm back to decrementing down to "johna". So-- I still have a problem.

Comment: If there was a way to make it so that x string in y list only returned an x whole word in the y list, that would solve my problem. But I cannot figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

```
firstMiddle = "johnadam"
nameToCheck = firstMiddle
nameList = ['johnathan', 'john', 'kate', 'sam']

while nameToCheck not in nameList:
    nameToCheck = nameToCheck[:-1]
firstname = nameToCheck
middleName = firstMiddle[ len(firstName): ]
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, but startswith would cause the same problem I identified in my OP when I said that "if you increment you fail."

Comment: @AutomaticStatic Sorry what? This is a prefectly valid solution for matching names.

Comment: @JamesMills I'm not looking to see if a specific first name is in the list. I'm trying to figure out which parts of a concatenated string are the first name and the middle. I have no idea what the first name is ahead of time-- the whole point is that i'm trying to deduce it with this loop.

Comment: I think what the OP wants is that rather than looking for `if firstMiddle.startswith( firstName ):`, which would result in the *first* match, you could do: `filter(lambda m: firstMiddle.startswith(m), nameList)`, and then find the longest first name that matches. I like your partition function. Its just a simple addition, and your method is otherwise fine.

Comment: i added a decrementing solution that will match the longest sub-string in nameToCheck that appears in nameList

Comment: @Gabriel thank you, but this is still going down to "johna." Seems my problem is proximate to not matching a whole word. Is it time for an object lesson in using a variable with regex? I have no idea how, of course!

Comment: @ssm thank you. I'm not 100% sure how to implement this. I tried putting this filter line in my for loop but it just runs forever. Sorry I don't have any experience with the lambda function. I literally started teaching myself python about 3 hours ago.

Comment: did you try running it?  I don't get a match for 'johna'

Comment: @Gabriel yeah I just subbed your decrementing code in where my for loop was and I'm still getting "johna". Tried resetting my kernel and everything. It's matching "johna" in "johnathan". This was the same thing I tried earlier when I did `while nameToCheck not in nameList...` It seems the problem is really the whole word issue.

Comment: something must be different in your code compared to what i have posted.  `'johna' in nameList` will return `False` for the `nameList` defined above.

Comment: do you have 'johna' in your list of first names?

Comment: I also don't see how `johna` will match. `jo` might if it were present. Unfortunately we are not sure if `jhona` is present in the nameList. That is the only way in which that match will return True.

Comment: yea, agree, `jo` would but not before `john`

Comment: @Gabriel `"johna" in nameList
Out[3]: True` I have personally checked there is no single name "johna" in the file. It only appears once, within the name "johnathan"

Comment: OMG there is a JOHNA. Sorry everyone!

Comment: bingo ;) please accept my answer by clicking the green check if it's working for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple change from what Gabriel has done. The concept is basically the same. This one just looks at the longest match rather than the first match. Its difficult to put the entire code in the comment section so answering separately.

```
firstMiddle = "johnadam"
nameToCheck = firstMiddle
nameList = ['johnathan', 'john', 'kate', 'sam']

firstNames = filter(lambda m: firstMiddle.startswith(m), nameList)
middleName = ''
if firstNames: # if the list isnt empty
    firstName = sorted( firstNames, key=len )[-1]
    middleName = firstMiddle.partition(firstName)[2]
else: 
    firstName = firstMiddle


print firstName
```

See if this works ...

Comment: I tried implementing this and it doesn't seem to be working at all. When I tried using just your filter/lambda bit earlier, it returned "johnadam". It's doing the same thing now. I even tried writing `nameList = ['johnathan']` to rule out some problem with the text file reading but no dice.

Comment: What does `filter(lambda m: "johnadam".startswith(m), ['johnathan', 'john', 'kate', 'sam'])` give you?

Comment: If the above statement gives you `['jonh']`, and `filter(lambda m: firstMiddle.startswith(m), nameList)` gives you something else, then either your `firstMiddle` or your `nameList`is different from the above. Both conditions simultaneously cannot be true.

Comment: You could use firstMiddle.__contains__(m) in your filter so multiple matchs could be found. like ['john','nathan','johnathan']

Comment: @ssm `filter(lambda m: nameToCheck.startswith(m), ['johnathan', 'john', 'kate', 'sam'])
Out[4]: ['john']
#OK let's try with the txt file read
filter(lambda m: nameToCheck.startswith(m), nameList)
Out[5]: 'jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj' #actually many more j's in the real thing

#can this be true?
"john" in nameList
Out[6]: True #WTFFFFFFFF`

Comment: mixnames = ['johnadam','johnathan','johnamax']
names = ['john','adam', 'johnathan','nathan','max']

for i in xrange(len(mixnames)):
    f = filter(lambda m: mixnames[i].__contains__(m), names)
    print f

Comment: `filter` returns a `list`. The `nameList` looks really suspicious. Even if you somehow got `'jjjjj...'` or something, the output would be `['jjj ....', ....]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a brute force way.

Iterate over the mixedname and slice it every time a bit more.

So you get

```
['johnadam']
['johnada','m']
['johnad','am']
['johna','dam']

['john','adam'] # your names in the list
```

If one of them match you put them aside and keep doing it until all of them are match.

If you have names that start same like 'john' and 'johnathan' or are in middle of other names, like 'natham' and 'johnathan' you should not stop when you find a match, but keep doing the slicing, so you get ['**john**','athan'] and ['joh','**nathan**']

```
mixnames = ['johnadam','johnathan','johnamax']
names = ['john','adam', 'johnathan','nathan','max']

foundnames = []
for name in mixnames:
    for i in xrange(len(name)):
        name1 = name[0:i+1]
        name2 = name[i:]
        if name1 in names and name1 not in foundnames:
            foundnames.append(name1)
        if name2 in names and name2 not in foundnames:
            foundnames.append(name2)

print foundnames
```

output:

```
['john', 'adam', 'johnathan', 'nathan', 'max']
```